# SQL string limits my numerics to 3 digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql string like this :

```
set @sql1 = 'select @DClose = DClose FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @filePath1 + '' + ';' + '''' + ',''Select * from [Sheet1$]'''+')'
```

The data comes from a csv file that I download everyday with market prices.
The price look like this:

```
Date         Price
7/31/2014    123.765625
```

When I convert my variable with this:

```
set @Price = cast(@DClose as numeric(20,10))
```

I get only this:

```
123.7660000000
```

instead of

```
123.765625
```

Is there a way to have the full number?

Here is a clean code:

```
 DECLARE @filePath1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @sym1 NVARCHAR(10)
  DECLARE @DDate date
  DECLARE @DClose NVARCHAR(35)
  DECLARE @WhereClause NVARCHAR(MAX) 
  DECLARE @Price  NUMERIC(20,10)

  SET @DDate = '08-01-2014' 

  SET @sym1 = 'excelFileName'
  SET @filePath1 = 'somefilepath\'

  SET @WhereClause = ' WHERE DDate =' + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), @DDate, 126) + CHAR(39)

  SET @sql1 = 'SELECT @DClose = DClose FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @filePath1 + '' + ';' + '''' + ',''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'''+')' 
  SET @sql1 = @sql1 + @WhereClause

  EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @sql1, N'@DClose NVARCHAR(35) OUTPUT' , @DClose OUTPUT

  SET @Price = CAST(@DClose AS NUMERIC(20,10))
```

Comment: What data type does Excel think the cell / column is where 123.765625 is stored?

Comment: What is @DClose if you don't cast it?

Comment: What type @DClose Declared?

Comment: `@Price` is set from `@DClose` so you need to trace `@DClose` first, then worry about `@Price`. We don't see how `@DClose` is established in the snippets you have in the question

Comment: Correction the data is stored everyday as an .xls file not csv.
DClose is a column with the close prices
Every File has a DDate Column and a DClose columns
If I open the file with Excel I see all the digits

Comment: @Susilo
 execute sp_executesql sql1, N'DClose NVarchar(35) output' , DClose OUTPUT
DClose needs to be Nvarchar(35) and after I get the results in string I Cast it in numeric
(Can't put the "at" sign before variable in that edit, stackoverflow consider it as a user)

Comment: @Used_by_Already
Even if Dclose is a numeric in Excel file I have to import it as a nvarchar. String query doesn't allow me to mix type. After it is stored in a variable I cast it back in numeric but I lose some digit even if nvarchar(35) is large enough to store all the digits.

Comment: @nicomp Since I can do arithmetic operations with it in Excel without conversion I believe it's a number not a string

Comment: @Adrian Lynch
This DClose variable is a Nvarchar(35) so it could work in execute sp_executesql

Comment: Can we see where you declare @DClose?

Comment: @Adrian Lynch
I tried to add the full code but Stackoverflow wont allow me. The edit box is very limited

Comment: @Adrian Lynch I added in the original post

Comment: You have the setting of `@DClose`, but where do you `DECLARE` it?

Comment: @Adrian Lynch Line 5

Comment: What do you get if you run this in your client: `DECLARE @dcClose NVARCHAR(35); SET @dcClose = '123.765625'; SELECT CAST(@dcClose AS NUMERIC(20, 10))`

Comment: I get this: 123.7656250000